# Print button not working by using Webview2 to render a PDF in an UWP app

Tags: uwp, webview2, winui

I'm trying to create an UWP app and embed a WebView2 in WinUI 2. Then I try to render a PDF host in a remote server in the WebView2, the PDF can be rendered normally, but when I clcik the print button in the toolbar, nothing happen and no printing preview dialog display. May I know it's a known issue? Thanks.

[image: print button]

WebView2 Runtime: 109.0.1518.52

Framework: UWP target to 18362

OS: Win10 20H2

WinUI2 2.8.1

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that you are using about WebView2? And what is the print button? Do you mean a built-in button for the WebView2?

Comment: I just set the webview2 source to a URL host a pdf. WebView2.Source = new Uri("http://www.xxx.xxx/test.pdf"), the print button is belong to the toolbar of the PDFViewer.

Comment: I've tested this in both UWP and WinUI3 with as online PDF file. The print button does not work in the UWP app, but it works in WinUI3 app. It seems that the `Webview2` control is not calling the print function in UWP correctly. You might need to report this issue in the WinUI Github:https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml

Comment: Thanks for the confirm. I will try to report it with my personal device.

Comment: I reported it here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3135

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I will also monitor this issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment its a known limitation that printing in a UWP app is not supported. This is described a bit more in the [WebView2 WinUI2 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2#default-printing).

For anyone who is running into this, please provide additional feedback to the WebView2 team on the [WebView2 WinUI2 printing GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3135).